# READ/WRITE phone storage from a cordova app(Android Marshmello +)

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm using below code to download and sava a file in my phone storage.

```
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
fileTransfer.download(
"http://developer.android.com/assets/images/home/ics-android.png",
"/storage/emulated/0/Download/ics-android.png",
function(entry) {
    alert("download complete: " + entry.fullPath);
},
function(error) {
    alert("download error source " + error.source);
    alert("download error target " + error.target);
    alert("upload error code" + error.code);
});
```

This code is working fine on any android device which are running on Android Lollipop or below. But from Android Marshmellow this doesn't work and return following error.

```
download error source " the url used"
download error target: " the target used  "
upload error code 1
```

Can someone help me to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions/ model for it.

You need `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` and `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` for it.

You can use below example for it. I got this example code from above-mentioned page. Go through it and add what you want.

```
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).then(
  result => console.log('Has permission?',result.hasPermission),
  err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
);

this.androidPermissions.requestPermissions([this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE]);
```